# Install command-line tools in Mac OS X El Captain using bash

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to install command-line tools in Mac OS X El Captain using bash.

> xcode-select --install

Running the above command pops up a window and asks the user to select install. How can I install the command-line tool without this popup window?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to preceed it with:

```
 sudo xcodebuild -license
```